# Suffix -sk[a/i] for adjectives derrived from nations in Nordic and some Slavic languages

Tags: grammar, slavic-languages, polish, old-norse, swedish

I was wondering about the ending -sk(+ optionally an additional vowel) used to create adjectives from names of the nations in Nordic (at least Danish and Swedish) as well as some Slavic languages (at least Polish and Croatian).

For example (the following lines are in format: English: Danish, Swedish, Croatian, Polish):

- Danish: Dan**sk**, Dan**sk**a, Dan**sk**[i/a]*, Duń**sk**[i/a]*
- Polish: Pol**sk**, Pol**sk**a, Polj**sk**[i/a]*, Pol**sk**[i/a]*
- English: Engel**sk**, Engel**sk**a, Engle**sk**[i/a]*, Angiel**sk**[i/a]*

* -i - masculine form, -a - feminine form. Not to add irrelevant details I didn't mention suffixes for neuter and plural forms.

Don't know about the other languages but in Polish -sk[i/a] is used also for some other adjectives:

- król (king) -> królew**sk**i/królew**sk**a (royal)
- papież (pope) -> papie**sk**i/papie**sk**a (papal)
- zielarz (herbalist) -> zielar**sk**i/zielar**sk**a (herbal)
- niebo (sky) -> niebie**sk**i/niebie**sk**a (blue)

And many surnames:

- kowal (blacksmith) -> Kowal**sk**i/Kowal**sk**a (the most popular Polish surname)
- jabłoń (apple-tree) -> Jabłoń**sk**i/Jabłoń**sk**a
- wiśnia (cherry) -> Wiśniew**sk**i/Wiśniew**sk**a

etc.

Is it something Proto-Indo-European, or it's just a coincidence? If it's a coincidence, how did it appear in Nordic languages? (If I'm not mistaken -ski ending was used already in Proto-Slavic.)

Comment: I think for the other Germanic languages, it's the cognate to English "ish" or German "isch." Modern English "sh" corresponds to Old English "sc."

Comment: Yes.  And in Latin languages there is *-isco* / *-esco* (eg *theodiscus*, *romanesco*).  See [wiktionary:-iskos](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Indo-European/-iskos) and [wiktionary:-ish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ish#English).

Comment: There is an english word for "papieski". It's "papal".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The suffix *-isk- is Indo-European. It has offspring in Greek, Germanic, Baltic and Slavic, and also in Romance, where it seems to be borrowed from Germanic.

Comment: Can you give any sources? Wiktionary refers to the same suffix as [*-iskos](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Indo-European/-iskos)

Comment: @J-mster. *-iskos is the suffix *-isk- plus thematic vowel plus case ending for the nominative singular.

Comment: for the masculine nominative singular.